# What happens when you do a comparison "date <= datetime" in SQL-server?

Tags: sql-server, date, datetime, casting, comparison

What happens when you do a comparison "date <= datetime" in SQL-server?

Are they both cast to date or are they both cast to datetime in order to do the comparison?

Comment: You should try this yourself and find out.

Comment: Or refer to the docs. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-precedence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16 - datetime has higher precedence than date so the date will be cast to datetime

Comment: @MartinSmith this is a perfect answer. Care to make it into an actual answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`datetime` has higher precedence than `date` so the `date` will be cast to `datetime`.

This is documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-precedence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16).

Or you can also see this below

```
DECLARE @D DATETIME = '2022-09-15 11:59:59';

SELECT CASE WHEN @D = CAST(@D AS DATE) THEN 'Equal' ELSE 'NotEqual' END
```

(Returns "NotEqual". If the implicit casting was to date and the time portion removed both would be equal)

Comment: If a column is date and it is compared with a datetime value/variable..then it is range compared with no casting (of date to datetime, index on date column is used)..etc

Comment: @lptr - looks like you get a ["dynamic seek"](https://www.sql.kiwi/2012/01/dynamic-seeks-and-hidden-implicit-conversions.html) in that case https://dbfiddle.uk/OfMfbIPs

Comment: @lptr That's only when indexes are involved. A regular predicate will just use a normal implicit cast